# Probability and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory

$ X,  Y,  Z$  and  $W $ are jointly  distributed  Bernoulli random  variables;  and  each of  these  can assume  values  $0$ or $1$ only.   It is known that  $X  =  max $ {$W,  Z$} and  $Y  =  min$  {$W,  Z$}. 
(a) If $E(X)  =  0.6$ and $E(Y) = 0.1$,  determine  the Conditional Expectation $E(X  \mid  Y  = 0)$.

(b) Determine  the  maximum  possible  value  of  $E(Y)$ if it is  only  known  that  $E(X) =  0.6$ ,(and there is no other numerical information available).

Comment: You can get the right spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: You can also get the right font by using `\min` and `\max`. For operators that don't have a predefined command, there's `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_{wz}=\textsf P(W=w\land Z=z)$. Then $\mathbb E(X)=1-p_{00}$, $\mathbb E(Y)=p_{11}$ and

$$
\mathbb E(X\mid Y=0)=\frac{1-p_{00}-p_{11}}{1-p_{11}}=\frac{\mathbb E(X)-\mathbb E(Y)}{1-\mathbb E(Y)}=\frac{0.5}{0.9}=\frac59\;.
$$

For b), $p_{00}+p_{11}\le1$ yields $\mathbb E(Y)\le\mathbb E(X)$, with equality achieved for $p_{01}=p_{10}=0$.